# Drools Workbench Non-readable POM

Tags: maven, docker, drools

I'm trying to use drools workbench to create rules, the following commands have been executed to pull the docker image and run a container:

```
    docker pull jboss/drools-workbench-showcase
    docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name drools-workbench jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest
```

The drools workbench gets up and running as expected, however, when I try to add project, Non-readable POM error shows up:
[image: add project error]

drools workbench error log:

```
2019-05-27 01:38:03,688 ERROR [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (EJB default - 1) Error while trying to
erase directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.18.0.Final
2019-05-27 01:38:03,689 ERROR [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-8) Error while trying to e
rase directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.18.0.Final
2019-05-27 01:38:03,694 ERROR [org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader] (Thread-241) Unable to creat
e MavenProject from InputStream: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while buil
ding the effective model
[FATAL] Non-readable POM : input contained no data @
 for project
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:126)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:308)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:91)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:84)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
        at org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:534)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:511)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:152)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:211)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:203)
        at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.core.Builder.build(Builder.java:213)
        at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.core.BuildHelper.build(BuildHelper.java:92)
```

My OS is Windows 10, and the Drools Workbench version is 7.18.Final, have I missed any configuration? I checked the official guide and searched the web, but haven't found solution yet.

Comment: Network issue cause the pom's couldn't be read ...

Comment: @khmarbaise, many thanks! you're right, it works now after switching to another network